# Ensure all dates are present in each group (eg retailer) in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to make sure, that for every groups I will have all dates presents (as I would like to have sum of rolling window of 7 days). My initial data has "blanks" in days that retailer was not selling products, and I would like to fill them with 0.

```
Initial data:
| Date | Retailer | Sales |
| ---- | -------- | ----- |
| 2024-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 2024-01-02 | A | 1 |
| 2024-01-01 | B | 9 |

Desired output:
| Date | Retailer | Sales |
| ---- | -------- | ----- |
| 2024-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 2024-01-02 | A | 1 |
| 2024-01-01 | B | 9 |
| 2024-01-02 | B | 0 |
```

Minimal code of my working, but not best, solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": ["2024-01-01", "2024-01-02", "2024-01-01"],
    "Retailer": ["A", "A", "B"],
    "Sales": [1, 1, 9], })

# create container df
unique_dates = df["Date"].unique()
container = pd.DataFrame()
for r in df["Retailer"].unique():
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({"Date": unique_dates})
    tmp["Retailer"] = r
    container = pd.concat([container, tmp], axis=0)
    
# join with orginal data
df_final = container.merge(df, on=["Date", "Retailer"], how="left")
# fill blanks
df_final = df_final.fillna(0)
#show
df_final
```

In my real life example there are multiple products, shops and long time series, so looping over everything is not best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": ["2024-01-01", "2024-01-02", "2024-01-01"],
    "Retailer": ["A", "A", "B"],
    "Sales": [1, 1, 9], })

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=list(product(df.Date.unique(), df.Retailer.unique())), columns=['Date', 'Retailer'])

df2 = df2.join(df, rsuffix='_to_drop')
df2 = df2[['Date', 'Retailer', 'Sales']]
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
```